# The basis of a matrix representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

If I have the linear map $f:\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^m$ then we can write $f$ as like the following:
$$f\left(\vec x\right)=A\vec x$$
Where $A$ is a matrix. I think $A$ is called the standard matrix for $f$. Linear maps act on vectors and therefore should not be associated with any basis i.e. they act on vectors rather then '[coordinate vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector)'. Does this mean that the matrix $A$ is not associated with any basis? (noting that in the standard basis of the two vector spaces, the matrix representatin of $f$ will be equivlent to $A$).

i.e. is the following statement correct:

> The matrix $A$ is equivalent to the linear map $f$ when acting on a vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$. The matrix $\tilde A$ which is the matrix representation of $f$ in the standard bases of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$  has exactly the same components as $A$ but acts on coordinate vectors rather then actual vectors the linear map $f$ acts on. These coordinate vectors will however take exactly the same form, in the standard bases, as the original vectors that $f$ acts on.

Comment: "Matrix representation" is a bit misleading as it may make people think of matrix representations of algebraic objects which is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen the notation $\tilde A$ used to mean $A$ w.r.t. the standard basis, but $A$ is ALWAYS w.r.t. *some basis*.  Think about it, matrices have components.  What would those components be if the matrix were not w.r.t. to some basis?

So $f$ is basis-free -- it doesn't matter which basis you choose, $f$ will always be the linear map that does a specific thing (determined by its definition is).

$A$ is basis-dependent.  You can only specify a matrix representation of a transformation $f$ if you've already chosen a basis.  And of course, the same matrix will NOT work if you later decide to change your basis (though you can transform it with an invertible matrix $P$ like $P^{-1}AP$).

$\tilde A$ is apparently the matrix representation of $f$ w.r.t. the *standard basis*.  This is of course, basis-dependent.

$\vec x$ is an object just like $f$.  By that I mean it is *intrinsicly* basis-free.  The coordinates of $\vec x$ are determined after a basis is chosen.  But we don't usually use any special notation to specify whether $\vec x$ is a coordinate vector or an abstract vector UNLESS we're doing a change of basis problem.

Comment: So if $A$ is basis dependent and $f$ is not then how can $f(\vec x)=A\vec x$ i.e. something that is independent of a basis equal something that is dependent on one?

Comment: Mathematicians often write things that are not logically true to save time.  In this case, they mean $[f(\vec x)]_{\beta} = A[\vec x]_{\beta}$, where the notation $[\cdot ]_{\beta}$, means the coordinate vector of the object w.r.t. the basis $\beta$.

Comment: Look at my edit.  A is acting on $[\vec x]_{\beta}$.  Both $A$ and $[\vec x]_{\beta}$ have components w.r.t. the basis $\beta$.

Comment: So are you saying that if we say $f(\vec x)=A \vec x$ then it has to be in a certain basis and if the basis is not implied then we should assume that it is the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$

Comment: Well... usually yes.  But occasionally, matrix-happy mathematicians will write down $f(\vec x) = A\vec x$ when they mean an *arbitrary* basis and thus, the basis is not necessarily the standard one.

Comment: Sorry, when you say arbitrary, you mean arbitrary and fixed rather then arbitrary and it can change

Comment: Yes.  Arbitrary and fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19469/discussion-between-joseph-and-bye-world).

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with this answer, and have posted another answer to explain my point of view. It is true that giving a matrix for a linear map is always with respect to some pair of bases. But for $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$ no _choice_ of basis is needed, if the standard bases are used. And saying "$A$ is basis-dependent" is nonsense, a matrix just is itself independently of any basis. And it defines a linear map on $\Bbb R^n$ by $v\mapsto A\cdot v$ (matrix multiplication) independently of any basis.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yeah... I wholeheartedly disagree with *your* answer, as well.  Look at the diagram in Thomas's answer. The mapping directly from $U$ to $V$ is given by the linear transformation $x \mapsto T(x)$, where $x\in U, T(x) \in V$.  This is basis independent, because we didn't need to choose a basis in either $U$ or $V$ to get the answer (though we will if we need the coordinates at some later point).  If we want to compute the result using matrix algebra, then we have to choose a basis in $U$ to map $x$ to some coordinate vector $[x]_{\mathcal B}$ and a basis in $V$...

Comment: so that we can interpret our result.  Then the entries of the matrix $S$ depend on the *bases chosen in* $U$ *and* $V$.  That's what I mean when I say that a matrix is always basis dependent.  Not that we're not using the standard basis on $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$, but that we need to have bases in $U$ and $V$ for the transformation $[x]_{\mathcal B} \mapsto S[x]_{\mathcal B}$ (where $S$ is the matrix representation of the linear transformation $T$) to be representative of the transformation $x \mapsto T(x)$.

Comment: Using this interpretation, we CAN choose other bases on $\Bbb R^n$, map that to the standard basis, perform matrix algebra, and then map back to the basis you care about in $\Bbb R^m$.  I don't see much point in doing so, but nonetheless I see it in Linear Algebra questions professors assign all the time.

Comment: But this question was not about linear maps $U\to V$, it was about linear maps $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$. In other words, in the diagram it is about $S$, not $T$. The correspondence between $S$ and a matrix is canonical, depending on nothing (while indeed as you indicated this is not so for $T$). In fact did you notice you actually called $S$ a matrix (while officially it remains a linear map)? This is understandable, because the correspondence between $S$ and a matrix is canonial.

Comment: I am making a distinction between $\Bbb R^n$ as "coordinate space" whose linear maps are always performed by matrices (because it's the easiest way once you've already got the coordinates) and $\Bbb R^n$ as a (slightly) more general vector space.  Coordinate space always uses the standard basis.  However, sometimes it is useful to choose another basis on $\Bbb R^n$ proper.  Then there *would* be a matrix we could use to go directly from $U$ to $V$ ($\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$ wrt nonstandard bases) with a single matrix multiplication.  But that's just because matrices are powerful tools...

Comment: What's really going on is that first we are mapping the vector in $\Bbb R^n$ in a nonstandard basis to it's coordinate vector wrt to the standard basis, performing the linear transformation in the standard bases of $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$ and then retrieving the vector in $\Bbb R^m$ from its coordinates.  So, though our single matrix can hide that fact, we really are doing the same procedure as with $U$ and $V$.  That's my take on it, at least.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity assume that $n = m$.

First some general things. Let $U$ and $V$ be two real vectors spaces with dimension $n$. A linear transformation $T: U \to V$ is a map that satisfies that

$$T(\alpha u + v) = \alpha T(u) + T(v)$$
for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, since $U$ and $V$ are real vector spaces of dimension $n$ you have isomorphisms $\phi: U\simeq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\psi: V\simeq \mathbb{R}^n$. It is really all about these isomorphisms.

So you end up with a map $S: \mathbb{R}^n \to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U @>{T}>> V\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathbb{R}^n @>{S}>> \mathbb{R}^n
\end{CD}
$$
commutes.

Here the map $S$ will depend on the isomorphisms $U\simeq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\simeq \mathbb{R}^n$. $S$ is given  by a matrix $A$ such that $S(v) = Av$ for $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. The relation is that if $\{e_i\}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ then you get bases $\{f_i\}$ for $U$ and $\{g_i\}$ for $V$ such that $\phi^{-1}(e_i) = f_i$ and $\psi^{-1}(e_i) = g_i$. You can obviously also pick other bases. However, if you go with this, then you have that

$$
T(f_i) = \psi^{-1}(S\phi(f_i)) = \psi^{-1}(Se_i).
$$
And here $Se_i$ is exactly the $i$th column of the matrix $A$.

Comment: Hi I understand it for the general vector spaces $U$ and $V$ it is just when $U=\Bbb{R}^n$  and likewise for $V$ that I am getting confused.

Comment: I have asked a related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067854/what-is-bbbrn

Answer (score 0):

You are right that linear maps act on vectors, not on their coordinates. But in $\Bbb R^n$ their is no distinction between a vector and its coordinates in the standard basis: in general given any vector $v$ in a real vector space $V$ equipped with a basis $B$, the tuple of coordinates of $v$ with respect to $B$ *is* an element of$~\Bbb R^n$; but in the special case that $V=\Bbb R^n$ and $B$ is the standard basis, that element is just $v$ itself. This is what the standard basis is about: if you want to think of $v\in\Bbb R^n$ as holding the coordinates of some vector, but you have no abstract situation at hand, then you can still think of it as being the coordinates of *itself* with respect to the standard basis.

It is somewhat unfortunate though that the same word "vector" is used sometimes to denote a general element of an abstract vector space, and sometimes (as in "column vector") to denote an $n$-tuple of numbers, an element specifically of$~\Bbb R^n$.

Some people would make a distinction between $\Bbb R^n$ and the set of column vectors of size $n$. I don't think such a distinction is very useful; writing the elements of an $n$-tuple vertically is just a notational convention. In any case the two vector spaces are *canonically* isomorphic (meaning that one can point out a specific isomorphism without making any choices).

Similarly the vector space of $m\times n$ matrices with real entries is canonically isomorphic to the space $\mathcal L(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^m)$ of $\Bbb R$-linear maps $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$. The canonical isomorphism is given by $A\mapsto(v\mapsto A\cdot v)$ (matrix$\times$column-vector multiplication is defined independently of any choices of bases). Here one cannot say that it is just a notational matter, since one cannot construe matrices (which are just blocks of numbers) to *be* linear maps, but the correspondence is canonical nonetheless.

So to answer your question, you can distinguish $A$ from the linear map $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ that is corresponds to. But $A$ is really *the same* as the matrix $\tilde A$ of the linear map with respect to the standard bases of $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$. As you said those matrices have the same size and the same entries, and in the world of matrices that makes them equal, period. And no choice of basis is involved here: standard bases (of spaces of the form $\Bbb R^n$, which are the only ones to have them) are *always given, never chosen*.