# What is $\Bbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I earlier asked this question [The basis of a matrix representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067582/the-basis-of-a-matrix-representation/1067638?noredirect=1#comment2171608_1067638). I now have a another question related to the same topic.

The vector space $\Bbb{R}^n$ I have seen defined as all $n$-tuples of real numbers$^1$. But I think a more intuitive definition would be that $\Bbb{R}^n$ is simply the $n$-dimensional real space such as a plane for $n=2$ or a line for $n=1$. My problem with the first definition is that it seems like we have already specified a basis, namely $(i,j,k)$ for n=3, which themselves have no meaning as column vectors until we define them to be $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ and $ (0,0,1)$ respectively. Thus if we write vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ as column vectors we have already defined our basis and the tuples are therefore not basis independent objects.

So my point is that if we change basis, the $n$-order tuples will change but the actual  'arrow' from one point to another in the $n$-dimensional space will not. So surely this 'arrow' is the actual element $\Bbb{R}^n$ and the $n$-order tuple is its coordinate map.

Is this right or wrong? If it is right please could you give me a source where it states it explicitly, I have tried to look for one without success.

1. from http://www.math.vt.edu/people/dlr/m2k_svb01_vecspc.pdf

Answer (score 6):

No, it is wrong to consider $\Bbb R^n$ as an abstract vector space of dimension$~n$ without given basis. There is no concrete vector space that *precisely* models *the* abstract vector space of dimension$~n$ without given basis, though one can give many examples of vector spaces of dimension$~n$ that do not obviously come equipped with a basis. That is what abstraction is about; if you want to work in a basis independent way, just start "let $V$ be an $\Bbb R$-vector space of dimension$~n$" and you won't have a preferred basis.

But $\Bbb R^n$ is a concrete "gold standard" vector space that can serve as reference; any *other* vector space of dimension$~n$ is brought into isomorphism with $\Bbb R^n$ exactly be choosing an ordered basis in it. But $\Bbb R^n$ does not need this; it is in canonical bijection with itself (by the identity map), obviously. So no choice of basis is needed in $\Bbb R^n$. If you *must* talk about bases, then the mentioned identity isomorphism corresponds to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$, but this really serves as "unit to use for quantities that need no unit". So talking about things in $\Bbb R^n$ being basis independent is really meaningless, as no basis is needed.

I've said more about this in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1111216/18880). From which I will here just paraphrase: the spaces $\Bbb R^n$ are the worst possible examples of vector spaces to learn about the meaning and usefulness of bases. (Unfortunately, they are also the easiest examples to talk about concretely.) When using in $\Bbb R^n$ another basis than the standard basis, we get from it an isomorphism $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ other than the identity. So one needs to distinguish between "abstract vectors" on one side of the isomorphism, and "their coordinates" on the other side, even though both live in the same space, and are unequal. You are quite right that this is utterly confusing. So when doing things basis independently *don't work in $\Bbb R^n$*.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I completely understand what you are asking. But, anyway...

It is all about definitions. You can take, as a definition, that 
$$\mathbb{R}^n = \left\{\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n} \mid x_i\in \mathbb{R}\right\}.$$

This defines what $\mathbb{R}^n$ is as a set. We make this into a vector spaces by defining the usual vector addition and scalar multiplication. All this we do without even thinking about what a basis is.

After defining what $\mathbb{R}^n$ is we then realize that we can write all the elements/vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a unique way as a linear combination of the vectors
$$
e_1 = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0}, e_2 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0}, e_3 = \cdots
$$
Saying this is exactly saying that this collection of vectors $\{e_1\}$ is a basis.

Now, it turns out that you can find other bases. No matter what basis you pick, the elements are the same. The space/set doesn't depend on the choice of basis that you might (might not) make.

---

After this we now understand what $\mathbb{R}^n$ is and what a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is. It turns out that it makes sense to talk about general vector spaces. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just an example of a vector space.

A general vector space is a set that satisfies certain requirements: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition

It then turns out that if $U$ is a general vector space of dimension $n$, then as vector spaces $U$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. They are not equal, but isomorphic. So in a sense there is only one vector space of dimension $n$ (for each $n$). We say that up to isomorphism there is only one vector space of dimension $n$.

Comment: Hi this now leads me back to my other question (see link above) that if the linear map $f$ acts on $\Bbb{R}^n$ and is given by the action of the matrix $A$ on a vector $\vec v$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$  such that $f(\vec v)=A\vec v$ then what basis is $A$ in if, as you have stated above $\Bbb{R}^n$ itself is not in a particular basis

Comment: @Joseph: $A$ is not "in a basis". $A$ is just a matrix independent of basis. You have bases for vector spaces.

Comment: So it is not representing the linear map in a particular basis and just represents it on a general vector?

Comment: i.e. Is the other answer to the linked question wrong (in your opinion)?

Comment: @Thomas I disagree that a matrix can *ever* be independent of basis.  Though the basis can be unspecified and arbitrary.

Comment: @Joseph: I am not saying that the other answer is wrong. But you can easily talk about matrices without talking about bases. The things is, though, that there is a relation to vector spaces and bases. I have tried to outline this connection in my answer above. If you are asking from the point of view of someone just learning linear algebra, I would suggest that you just view matrices as rows and columns of numbers. It sounds like you are just considering matrices with entries from the real numbers, but it makes fine sense to talk about matrices with entries from other "things".

Comment: @Bye_World: The point is that when you start learning linear algebra you start talking about matrices much before talking about vector spaces and bases. The connection be bases comes later and it sounds like this OP isn't quite there yet. So I think it is better to keep things simple. You are free to disagree of course.

Comment: @Thomas I have learned the connection between basis, vector spaces and matrices. I am fine with all other cases, it is just the case when the linear map is defined as a matrix. I am fine also with the fact that all linear maps can be represented by matrices.

Comment: @Joseph: Ok. Did you read my answer to the OP's other question?

Comment: @Thomas Yes I did, but it seems that you are just talking about  a general linear map $T$ from two arbitrary vector spaces $U$ and $V$. Which is something I understand. It is when those two vector spaces are $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$ and when T is donated by a matrix I get confused?

Comment: @Joseph: Sorry, I had actually meant that comment to Bye_World. Oh well. You can take $U$ and $V$ in that other answer as $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the isomorphisms as identities.

Comment: @Thomas You were talking to me?  Yes.  I read your other answer.  And I agree with it.  I agree with what you have here as well.  I only answered here after you because I thought I could provide a little more insight with my "mathematicians/ physicists/ (any other people practicing a formal discipline) are lazy" ideology. :)

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb R^n$ is the set of all $n$-tuples.  But because there is a theorem which says that every $n$-dimensional vector space over the reals is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, mathematicians (being lazy) don't often distinguish between their $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ and $\Bbb R^n$ unless they have to.

So while $\Bbb R^n$ is defined to mean the set of all $n$-tuples, it's generally ALSO conflated with Euclidean space, "arrow" space (the set of all oriented line segments), and "coordinate" space.

$\Bbb R^n$ does not have an intrinsic basis.  We could in fact choose the basis $\left\{ f_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, f_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, f_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ or an uncountably infinite number of others for $\Bbb R^3$. It just turns out that the standard basis is more easily manipulated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, could you please provide source, for your answer to the linked question, this would be a great help. Thanks once gain.

Comment: @Joseph Source: any upper-division undergraduate book on Linear Algebra.  :)

Comment: For instance, Hoffman/ Kunze is a pretty good one.

Comment: @Joseph Actually, I'll revise my suggestion.  Pick up *Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces* by Paul Halmos.  It's absolutely fantastic.  The part dealing with your other question starts on page $65$ of my copy.

Comment: I am still confused. All I don't get is why we can't have a matrix $A$ that acts on vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ in exactly the same way as the linear map $f$ without been related to any basis? Please can you try and explain

Comment: Let us say we had f(x,y)=(2x,2y) which is a linear map on $\Bbb{R}^n$ why can't we define a matrix with components $a_{11}=2, a_{12}=0, a_{21}=0, a_{22}=2$ which is independent of any basis and simply  acts on the vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ rather then any coordinate vectors related to a specific basis?

Comment: Think about an arrow vector in a plane.  That arrow exists regardless of the coordinate system we stick around it.  Its "coordinates" relative to that coordinate system depend on exactly which basis vectors we choose for our coordinate system.  Then say we double the length of one of our coordinate vectors.  The arrow doesn't change, but its *coordinates* with respect to that new coordinate system are different.  A matrix is a way of representing a transformation of our vector with respect to the coordinate system that we've already chosen.

Comment: Because the $x$ and the $y$ depend on your choice of coordinates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19474/discussion-between-joseph-and-bye-world).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the unique $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space (up to isomorphism).

Now there are several ways to define it. As cartesian product it is the set:
$$
\{f\colon\{1,...,n\}\to\mathbb{R} : f\mbox{ is a function}\}
$$

Then, for convenience, we usually write the elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $n$-tuples.

However, in full generality, if we have a field $k$ and a finite dimensional $k$-vector space $V$. Then, by standard results, we know that $V$ has a basis $\mathscr{B}=\{u_1,...,u_n\}$. In particular, for any vector $u\in V$ we have
$$
u=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iu_i,
$$
where $\lambda_i\in k$. Thus we can define the coordinate function:
$$
c_{\mathscr{B}}\colon V\to k^n,\ u\mapsto(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n),
$$
which is an isomorphism of vector spaces. (This is the reason why I said that $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.)

If we consider another basis $\mathscr{B}'=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, then we have another coordinate function $c_{\mathscr{B}'}$.

If we want to change basis then we have to extend by linearity the map:
$$
\varphi_{\mathscr{B},\mathscr{B}'}\colon V\to V,\ u_i\mapsto v_i.
$$
This map can be seen as $c_{\mathscr{B}'}^{-1}\circ\varphi\circ c_{\mathscr{B}}\colon k^n\to k^n$. So this is the map you apply to your number $n$-tuples when you change basis.

Notice that if you consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the plane and you draw two orthogonal lines and draw the vector (or arrow) $(3,2)$ then this is $3(1,0)+2(0,1)$. But if you change basis, this vector will change (as picture). Try to draw this example and then the same with basis $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ so that $(3,2)=(1,0)+2(1,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_power) involves Cartesian product of sets: $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\underset{n\text{ times}}{\underbrace{\mathbb{R}\times\dots\times\mathbb{R}}}$ which constists of ordered n-tuples. Elements of $\mathbb R$ happen to be real numbers. So to me, it doesn't seem "like we have already specified a basis". We haven't even said yet that it is a vector space.