# Matrix associated with a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $$b(v,w)=\begin{pmatrix} x_v& y_v& z_v \end{pmatrix} A \begin{pmatrix} x_w \\ y_w \\ z_w\\\end{pmatrix},$$ (where $A$ is the matrix associated with the bilinear form $b$ defined on $\mathbb{R^3}$). Is it true that $x_v, y_v, z_v$ and $x_w, y_w, z_w$ should be the components of $v$ and $w$ with respect to the basis for which we have written $A$?

Comment: Given that you are working in $\Bbb R^3$, everything will be expressed in the standard basis; the $(x,y,z)$ are just the components of your vector itself (no basis involved). But if you are working in any vector space of dimension$~3$ _other_ than  $\Bbb R^3$ (for instance a subspace of some $\Bbb R^n$ with $n>3$), then you need a basis of that space in order to get coordinates in the first place, and to describe $b$ by a $3\times3$ matrix. Of course you need to use the _same basis_ for doing those two things. See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1111216/18880)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes true! To see this let $v=\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i e_i$ and $w=\sum_{j=1}^3 x'_je_j$ so

$$b(v,w)=b\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i e_i,\sum_{j=1}^3 x'_je_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3x_ix'_j b(e_i,e_j)$$

so with $A=(b(e_i,e_j))_{1\le i,j\le3}$ we get

$$b(v,w)=V^TAW$$
where $V=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ and $W=(x'_1,x'_2,x'_3)^T$ the coordinates of $v$ and $w$ respectively.